# Android Mono Runtime Installed everytime when i start debug

Tags: android, runtime

VS2012 install runtime to android device everytime when i click on Start Debug button.
How can i disable installing shared run-time everytime ?

Everytime when i click on Start Debug button, this started:

> Waiting for device..
>   1>Detecting installed packages
>   1>Detecting installed packages...
>   1>Removing old runtime
>   1>Removing old runtime: Mono.Android.DebugRuntime...
>   1>
>   1>Installing shared runtime
>   1>Target device is armeabi-v7a.
>   1>Installing the Mono shared runtime (armeabi-v7a - 1368726566)...
>   1>
>   1>
>   1>Removing old runtimes
>   1>Removing old runtime: Mono.Android.DebugRuntime [2147483647]..
>   1>Removing old runtime: Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_10 [2147483647]..
>   1>
>   1>Installing shared runtime
>   1>Target device is armeabi-v7a.
>   1>Installing the Mono shared runtime (armeabi-v7a - 1368726566)...
>   1>
>   1>Installing platform framework
>   1>Installing the API 10 platform framework..
>   1>
>   1>Getting installation path...
>   1>Synchronizing assemblies...
>   1>Synchronizing assemblies
>   ...

Comment: Problem: /data/system/packages.xml is not accessible in Android 4.1

Comment: Related bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15553